# Passing an Action with Different Parameters

Tags: c#, action

I have a class in C# named `Button` and I want the `Button` have a functionality that can be passed through its constructor and whenever the `Button` was pressed the `Action` executes.

```
Button(Rect rect, string text, Action Func);
```

I have used `Action` and It worked perfectly until I found out that I can't pass a `void Action` with arguments.

For example:

```
void DoSomething(string str);
```

How can I be able to pass any `void Action` with any arguments?

Comment: If your button doesn't actually care about str, you can pass '() => DoSomething("aStr")' as a Func parameter value (which btw should probably be renamed action)

Comment: You may declare Action as void with an object[] parameter. for example, *void DoSomething(object [] objects) { string inputstring=(string)Objects[0]; }*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button doesn't have to care about the argument, but it still needs to be passed a delegate with no arguments and returning void. This is easily done:

```
new Button(rect, text, () => YourMethod(whateverArgument))
```

Depending on what you're trying to do, `whateverArgument` can be a local, a constant or a field. Just think about when it's supposed to read the value to pass to the inner method.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can pass arguments, just use the following:

```
Button b = new Button(.., .., () => DoSomething("YourString");
```

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to use simplefied [command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern):
Create base class or interface Command

```
interface ICommand
{
    void Execute();
}

//Create secific command and pass parameters in constructor:
class Command : ICommand
{
    public Command(string str)
    {
        //do smth
    }
    void Execute()
    {
        //do smth
    }
}

Button(Rect rect, string text, ICommand cmd)
{
    cmd.Execute();
}
```

Comment: This would be a decent idea if .NET didn't have delegates - since it does, there's little point. Even if it didn't have lambdas or anonymous methods, it would be easier to just wrap the action method in a delegate rather than switching over to some `ICommand` interface. Of course, a command might still be a better choice if the action isn't the *only* thing you care about. If it is, just stick to delegates.